# Gap in border lines in longtable while using \cmidrule(r{}){}

Tags: longtable, border, gap

I added two horizontal line in a `longtable` header using `\cmidrule(r{}){}` which made some gaps in border lines, would you mind telling me how I can fix it?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}   
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
    \lipsum[2]
    {\small
    \rowcolors{2}{white}{gray!15}
    \begin{longtable}{|lcccccccc|} 
        \rowcolor{white}
        \caption{Prior information (parameters)}\\
        \hline%
        \rowcolor{white}
        \multicolumn{1}{|c}{}&  &  &  &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Bounds} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{90\% HPDI} \\  
        \cmidrule(r{.75em}){6-7} \cmidrule(r{.75em}){8-9}
        \rowcolor{white}
        & Distribution & Mean & Mode & Std.dev. & Lower & Upper & Lower & Upper  \\ 
        \hhline{=========}%
        \endfirsthead
        \rowcolor{white}
        \multicolumn{9}{r}{(Continued on next page)} \\ 
        \hline%
        \rowcolor{white}
        \multicolumn{1}{|c}{}&  &  &  &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Bounds} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{90\% HPDI} \\  
        \cmidrule(r{.75em}){6-7} \cmidrule(r{.75em}){8-9}
        \rowcolor{white}
        & Distribution & Mean & Mode & Std.dev. & Lower & Upper & Lower & Upper  \\
        \hhline{=========}%
        \endhead
        \hline%
        \rowcolor{white}
        \multicolumn{2}{r}{(Next Page)} \\ 
        \endfoot
        \hline%
        \endlastfoot
        $ SE_{\varepsilon^{g}} $ & Inv. Gamma & 0.1130 & 0.0521 &    Inf & 0.0000 & $\infty$ & 0.0368 & 0.2815 \\ 
        $ SE_{\varepsilon^{z}} $ & Inv. Gamma & 0.1500 & 0.0691 &    Inf & 0.0000 & $\infty$ & 0.0489 & 0.3737 \\ 
        $ SE_{\varepsilon^{o}} $ & Inv. Gamma & 0.1550 & 0.0714 &    Inf & 0.0000 & $\infty$ & 0.0505 & 0.3861 \\ 
        $ SE_{\varepsilon^{P^{o,f}}} $ & Inv. Gamma & 0.1420 & 0.0654 &    Inf & 0.0000 & $\infty$ & 0.0463 & 0.3537 \\ 
        $ SE_{\varepsilon^{gm}} $ & Inv. Gamma & 0.1500 & 0.0691 &    Inf & 0.0000 & $\infty$ & 0.0489 & 0.3737 \\ 
        $ \bar{\pi} $ & Uniform & 1.0425 & NaN & 0.0072 & 1.0300 & 1.0550 & 1.0313 & 1.0538 \\ 
        $ \phi_{p} $ & Gamma & 60.0000 & 59.5833 & 5.0000 & 0.0000 & $\infty$ & 52.0193 & 68.4543 \\ 
        $ \rho^{g} $ & Beta & 0.4000 & 0.3978 & 0.0500 & 0.0000 & 1.0000 & 0.3189 & 0.4835 \\ 
        $ \rho^{g,r} $ & Beta & 0.8000 & 0.8098 & 0.0500 & 0.0000 & 1.0000 & 0.7126 & 0.8765 \\ 
        $ \alpha^{g} $ & Beta & 0.4000 & 0.3978 & 0.0500 & 0.0000 & 1.0000 & 0.3189 & 0.4835 \\ 
        $ \upsilon $ & Gamma & 1.0000 & 0.9900 & 0.1000 & 0.0000 & $\infty$ & 0.8414 & 1.1700 \\ 
        $ {\xi} $ & Beta & 0.1000 & 0.0991 & 0.0100 & 0.0000 & 1.0000 & 0.0841 & 0.1169 \\ 
        $ \sigma $ & Gamma & 4.0000 & 3.9375 & 0.5000 & 0.0000 & $\infty$ & 3.2146 & 4.8564 \\ 
        $ \beta $ & Beta & 0.9800 & 0.9800 & 0.0010 & 0.0000 & 1.0000 & 0.9783 & 0.9816 \\ 
        $ \alpha $ & Beta & 0.5500 & 0.5510 & 0.0500 & 0.0000 & 1.0000 & 0.4671 & 0.6317 \\ 
        $ \rho^{z} $ & Beta & 0.7000 & 0.7222 & 0.1000 & 0.0000 & 1.0000 & 0.5242 & 0.8525 \\ 
        $ \eta $ & Gamma & 2.0000 & 1.9950 & 0.1000 & 0.0000 & $\infty$ & 1.8384 & 2.1673 \\ 
        $ \rho^{o} $ & Beta & 0.7000 & 0.7049 & 0.0500 & 0.0000 & 1.0000 & 0.6150 & 0.7795 \\ 
        $ \rho^{P^{O,f}} $ & Beta & 0.2500 & 0.2497 & 0.0100 & 0.0000 & 1.0000 & 0.2337 & 0.2666 \\ 
        $ \rho^{gm} $ & Beta & 0.5500 & 0.5502 & 0.0200 & 0.0000 & 1.0000 & 0.5170 & 0.5828 \\ 
        $ \rho^{\pi} $ & Gamma & 2.5000 & 2.4960 & 0.1000 & 0.0000 & $\infty$ & 2.3378 & 2.6667 \\ 
        $ \rho^{y} $ & Gamma & 2.6000 & 2.5846 & 0.2000 & 0.0000 & $\infty$ & 2.2800 & 2.9375 \\ 
        $ \rho^{gm,\delta h} $ & Gamma & 0.5000 & 0.5000 & 0.0050 & 0.0000 & $\infty$ & 0.4918 & 0.5083 \\ 
        $ \rho^{\delta h} $ & Gamma & 5.0000 & 4.9500 & 0.5000 & 0.0000 & $\infty$ & 4.2070 & 5.8499 \\ 
        $ \rho^{fr} $ & Gamma & 4.0000 & 3.9375 & 0.5000 & 0.0000 & $\infty$ & 3.2146 & 4.8564 \\ 
        $ \bar{\epsilon} $ & Beta & 0.2000 & 0.1996 & 0.0100 & 0.0000 & 1.0000 & 0.1838 & 0.2167 \\ 
        $ \sigma^{m} $ & Gamma & 0.7000 & 0.6429 & 0.2000 & 0.0000 & $\infty$ & 0.4066 & 1.0581 \\  
    \end{longtable}
}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: what you like to fix? Command `\cmidrule(r{}){}` works as intended. See if `\cmidrule(l){...}`  gives what you like to have.  Note, vertical lines as well as rowcolors doesn't work well with rules from `booktabs. See, if you can live without vertical lines ... Also your table is to wide that can be fit in text width.

Comment: look at the booktabs manual, the author believes vertical lines are evil and `|` not working with booktabs commands is by design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an effect of `booktabs` that expands the vertical space between rows, and breaks vertical lines of a table along the way.
(Sometimes I think `booktabs` deliberately sabotage vertical lines)

To defeat this unwanted behavior use instead

```
 \aboverulesep=0ex
 \belowrulesep=0ex
```

and the with the `array` package

```
 \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
```

expand them again.

`booktabs` is still  useful to trim the `\cmidrule` to make them not touching each other. I suggest something like

```
 \cmidrule(r{.45em} l{.50em}){6-7} \cmidrule(r{.8em}l{.7em}){8-9}
```

to make them more symmetrical and optically centered.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}   
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{array} % added

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
    \lipsum[2]
    
    \aboverulesep=0ex  % added
    \belowrulesep=0ex  % added
     
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}  % added
    {\small
    \rowcolors{2}{white}{gray!15}
    \begin{longtable}{@{}|lcccc cc  cc|} 
        \rowcolor{white}
        \caption{Prior information (parameters)}\\
        \hline%
        \rowcolor{white}
        \multicolumn{1}{|c}{}&  &  &  &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Bounds} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{90\% HPDI} \\   [-0.5pt]
      \cmidrule(r{.75em}){6-7} \cmidrule(r{.75em}){8-9} 
        \rowcolor{white}
        & Distribution & Mean & Mode & Std.dev. & Lower & Upper & Lower & Upper  \\ 
        \hhline{=========}%
        \endfirsthead
        \rowcolor{white}
        \multicolumn{9}{r}{(Continued on next page)} \\ 
        \hline%
        \rowcolor{white}
        \multicolumn{1}{|c}{}&  &  &  &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Bounds} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{90\% HPDI} \\  [-0.5pt]
        \cmidrule(r{.75em}){6-7} \cmidrule(r{.75em}){8-9}
        \rowcolor{white}
        & Distribution & Mean & Mode & Std.dev. & Lower & Upper & Lower & Upper  \\
        \hhline{=========}%
        \endhead
        \hline%
        \rowcolor{white}
        \multicolumn{2}{r}{(Next Page)} \\ 
        \endfoot
        \hline%
        \endlastfoot
        $ SE_{\varepsilon^{g}} $ & Inv. Gamma & 0.1130 & 0.0521 &    Inf & 0.0000 & $\infty$ & 0.0368 & 0.2815 \\ 
        $ SE_{\varepsilon^{z}} $ & Inv. Gamma & 0.1500 & 0.0691 &    Inf & 0.0000 & $\infty$ & 0.0489 & 0.3737 \\ 
        $ SE_{\varepsilon^{o}} $ & Inv. Gamma & 0.1550 & 0.0714 &    Inf & 0.0000 & $\infty$ & 0.0505 & 0.3861 \\ 
        $ SE_{\varepsilon^{P^{o,f}}} $ & Inv. Gamma & 0.1420 & 0.0654 &    Inf & 0.0000 & $\infty$ & 0.0463 & 0.3537 \\ 
        $ SE_{\varepsilon^{gm}} $ & Inv. Gamma & 0.1500 & 0.0691 &    Inf & 0.0000 & $\infty$ & 0.0489 & 0.3737 \\ 
        $ \bar{\pi} $ & Uniform & 1.0425 & NaN & 0.0072 & 1.0300 & 1.0550 & 1.0313 & 1.0538 \\ 
        $ \phi_{p} $ & Gamma & 60.0000 & 59.5833 & 5.0000 & 0.0000 & $\infty$ & 52.0193 & 68.4543 \\ 
        $ \rho^{g} $ & Beta & 0.4000 & 0.3978 & 0.0500 & 0.0000 & 1.0000 & 0.3189 & 0.4835 \\ 
        $ \rho^{g,r} $ & Beta & 0.8000 & 0.8098 & 0.0500 & 0.0000 & 1.0000 & 0.7126 & 0.8765 \\ 
        $ \alpha^{g} $ & Beta & 0.4000 & 0.3978 & 0.0500 & 0.0000 & 1.0000 & 0.3189 & 0.4835 \\ 
        $ \upsilon $ & Gamma & 1.0000 & 0.9900 & 0.1000 & 0.0000 & $\infty$ & 0.8414 & 1.1700 \\ 
        $ {\xi} $ & Beta & 0.1000 & 0.0991 & 0.0100 & 0.0000 & 1.0000 & 0.0841 & 0.1169 \\ 
        $ \sigma $ & Gamma & 4.0000 & 3.9375 & 0.5000 & 0.0000 & $\infty$ & 3.2146 & 4.8564 \\ 
        $ \beta $ & Beta & 0.9800 & 0.9800 & 0.0010 & 0.0000 & 1.0000 & 0.9783 & 0.9816 \\ 
        $ \alpha $ & Beta & 0.5500 & 0.5510 & 0.0500 & 0.0000 & 1.0000 & 0.4671 & 0.6317 \\ 
        $ \rho^{z} $ & Beta & 0.7000 & 0.7222 & 0.1000 & 0.0000 & 1.0000 & 0.5242 & 0.8525 \\ 
        $ \eta $ & Gamma & 2.0000 & 1.9950 & 0.1000 & 0.0000 & $\infty$ & 1.8384 & 2.1673 \\ 
        $ \rho^{o} $ & Beta & 0.7000 & 0.7049 & 0.0500 & 0.0000 & 1.0000 & 0.6150 & 0.7795 \\ 
        $ \rho^{P^{O,f}} $ & Beta & 0.2500 & 0.2497 & 0.0100 & 0.0000 & 1.0000 & 0.2337 & 0.2666 \\ 
        $ \rho^{gm} $ & Beta & 0.5500 & 0.5502 & 0.0200 & 0.0000 & 1.0000 & 0.5170 & 0.5828 \\ 
        $ \rho^{\pi} $ & Gamma & 2.5000 & 2.4960 & 0.1000 & 0.0000 & $\infty$ & 2.3378 & 2.6667 \\ 
        $ \rho^{y} $ & Gamma & 2.6000 & 2.5846 & 0.2000 & 0.0000 & $\infty$ & 2.2800 & 2.9375 \\ 
        $ \rho^{gm,\delta h} $ & Gamma & 0.5000 & 0.5000 & 0.0050 & 0.0000 & $\infty$ & 0.4918 & 0.5083 \\ 
        $ \rho^{\delta h} $ & Gamma & 5.0000 & 4.9500 & 0.5000 & 0.0000 & $\infty$ & 4.2070 & 5.8499 \\ 
        $ \rho^{fr} $ & Gamma & 4.0000 & 3.9375 & 0.5000 & 0.0000 & $\infty$ & 3.2146 & 4.8564 \\ 
        $ \bar{\epsilon} $ & Beta & 0.2000 & 0.1996 & 0.0100 & 0.0000 & 1.0000 & 0.1838 & 0.2167 \\ 
        $ \sigma^{m} $ & Gamma & 0.7000 & 0.6429 & 0.2000 & 0.0000 & $\infty$ & 0.4066 & 1.0581 \\  
    \end{longtable}
}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

To close the small gap that remains add a small shift

```
 \multicolumn{1}{|c}{}&  &  &  &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Bounds} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{90\% HPDI} \\  [-0.5pt]
```

[image: gap]

The alternative without `booktabs`, with

```
   \cline{6-7} \cline{8-9}
```

does not look so nice.

[image: noBT]

Comment: Yes, `booktabs` should never be used for tables that have vertical lines.

Comment: @egreg It puzzles me to see so many questions asked, not as an interesting new challenge, but on how to avoid unwanted behavior from packages that otherwise provide many useful commands.
LaTeX is not immune to this. The floating problem (how to beat this nice feature) will remain for a long time.